# ASP.NET Profile Templates

Tags: .net, asp.net, profile, asp.net-profiles, system-configuration

Is it possible have more than one profile template?

I'm working on an internal application for a company that will be distributed to multiple locations and have different setups.  I was thinking of having a profile for user preferences, and then using the profile system to store system configuration information (I didn't want to load the web.config file down with configuration information), however I would need two separate profile templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web.config is the ideal location to store application settings. If your deploying to a farm and want a central location then a database might be another possibility.

You can use the [appsetting's file attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154.aspx) as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/appsettings_fileattribute.aspx) to externalize the actual configuration from the web.config if you need.

You can also use the [configsource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx) property to store a configuration section in an external file.